# How to Search for the unix executable file in OS X programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa

So, I need to search for the `Unix Executable files` in a directory. I Iterate through directory and with the path of the file I am searching. Some of the Methods I tried.

**1.With the Help of the file Extension**

`Unix Executable file` does not have the file Extension, but Some documents files are also not having the extensions. So, it failed for me.

**2. With the help of NSFileManager**

```
NSDicitionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```

It does not have any unique attributes to find the Unix executable file.

**3. With the help of MDItemRef**

It have the attribute called `kMDItemContentType` but it is giving the correct result for some of the `unix executable files` only.

```
MDItemRef        inspectedRef;
CFArrayRef       inspectedRefAttributeNames;
CFDictionaryRef  inspectedRefAttributeValues;
inspectedRef = MDItemCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)filePath);
if(inspectedRef) {
    inspectedRefAttributeNames = MDItemCopyAttributeNames(inspectedRef);
    inspectedRefAttributeValues = MDItemCopyAttributes(inspectedRef,inspectedRefAttributeNames);
    NSDictionary *attribDict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)inspectedRefAttributeValues;
    if([[attribDict objectForKey:@"kMDItemContentType"] isEqualToString:@"public.unix-executable"]) 
        NSLog(@"Unix Executable file");
}
```

**4. With the help of unix command "file"**

```
NSTask *unixTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[unixTask setStandardOutput:newPipe];
[unixTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/file"];
[unixTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filePath]]; 
[unixTask launch];
[unixTask waitUntilExit];
[unixTask terminationStatus];

while ((inData = [readHandle availableData]) && [inData length]) {
    returnValue= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inData encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    returnValue = [returnValue substringToIndex:[returnValue length]-1];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnValue);
}
```

Here, From the `returnValue` I can able to find whether it is unix executable or not. But it is very slow Process. So, My question is How to search for the unix executable in an efficient manner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using either getResourceValue:forKey:error: or resourceValuesForKeys:error: methods of NSURL and requesting NSURLTypeIdentifierKey.

Addendum:

If what @Aravindhanarvi says is correct, on 10.6 there are bugs and the above solution is unreliable. To make things worse @petur solution is also not possible for lack of NSURLIsExecutableKey.

An alternative would be to fall back to the NSFileManager and use methods like isExecutableFileAtPath: and attributesOfItemAtPath:error: (specifically the NSFilePosixPermissions and NSFileType attributes) to implement the same logic suggested by @petur.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For the Document type file also it is showing as Unix-executable file :(

Comment: I'm not sure what your previous comment means. Do you mean that NSURLTypeIdentifierKey property is "public.unix-executable" but the finder lists the file as "Document"? That sounds very strange to me.

Comment: ya.. I don't why it is showing the document file as unix-executable file.

Comment: You did not answer my questions. Is the file listed by Finder as "Document" or as "Unix Executable"? Is the file property "public.unix-executable" or something else?

Comment: It in finder it is showing as "Document" but in "NSURLTypeIdentifierKey" it is showing as Unix-executable file.

Comment: That's very very strange. What is the name and what are the contents of the file? Are the unix exec flags set for the file?

Comment: If you have Google chrome. See here /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/PkgInfo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15167/discussion-between-aravindhanarvi-and-analog-file)

Answer (score 2):

Came up with this, just point the url to the directory you to use as the base.
This is ARC code.

The array, files, contains an url pointer to each executable file found.

```
@autoreleasepool {

    NSFileManager *defaultFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/private/tmp/"]; // Search path
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator = [defaultFileManager enumeratorAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, nil] options:0 errorHandler:nil];

    NSMutableArray *files = [NSMutableArray array];

    // extract non-executable files
    for (NSURL *file in dirEnumerator) {
        NSNumber *isExecutable;
        NSNumber *isDirectory; // Directories have the executable flag set, but we are not interested in them
        NSError *error, *error2;
        [file getResourceValue:&isExecutable forKey:NSURLIsExecutableKey error:&error];
        [file getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error2];

        // Deal with errors
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        else if (error2)
            NSLog(@"%@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
        else if ([isExecutable boolValue] && ![isDirectory boolValue]) {
            [files addObject:file];
        }

    // print out all executable files to the console
    for (id i in files)
        NSLog(@"%@", [i description]);

}
```

Comment: NSURLIsExecutableKey is present only in 10.7. I want to do it in 10.6.

Comment: Please state such restrictions in the questions body next time :)